# My hive table has column of type map<String,String>. I would like to explode the map and transpose them into columns instead of rows

Tags: hadoop, hive

Following is my hive table structure

```
data_dt                 string
id                      string
records                 map<string,string>
```

It is partitioned by `data_dt`.

When I run the query,

```
select id, key, val from test
lateral view explode(records) t as key, val
```

As per Hive document, my map `records` gets exploded into rows of data. I need the exploded data in columns rather than in rows.

E.x: 
The above query will yield me

```
abc | k1 | v1
abc | k2 | v2
abc | k3 | v3
zxc | k1 | v1
zxc | k3 | v3
```

Instead I need it as follows

```
id  | k1 | k2 | k3
abc | v1 | v2 | v3
zxc | v3 | /N | v3
```

I know explode is a UDTF and hence it will dump results as rows rather than columns. But is there means to get the data as columns instead of rows?

Comment: Are there an arbitrary number of fields in the records map?  Do you need to all of those fields or just some?

Comment: I need all the fields from the map.

Comment: did you get any solution? I have the same kind of requirement

Comment: Doing this in post using R at the moment. e.g., `dcast(tbl, ... ~ key, value.var='val')`

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram like Clayton, I ended up using R for post process.

Comment: @HKrishnan you can add a rowId to the long form table if needed to make sure the dcast returns one row per record. Row_num over () (pseudocode) in a subquery in the Hive query

Answer (score 0):

You can run query like this:

```
select id, max(k1) as k1, max(k2) as k2, max(k3) as k3 from (
select id, case when c2 = 'k1' then c3 end as k1,
case when c2 = 'k2' then c3 end as k2,
case when c2 = 'k3' then c3 end as k3
from table_name) q;
```

Comment: The table is huge (approx 2 billion records) so having a case statement will not help me.. I'm looking for something more dynamic..